# Update Panel and newer versions of Webkit browsers

Tags: asp.net, webkit, updatepanel

I have several web tools that rely on update panels to update page content. I KNOW that as recently as a few weeks ago these all worked on iOS devices, and they used to work in Chrome. Now however I get...

Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: An unknown error occurred while processing the request on the server. The status code returned from the server was: 0

when ever a partial postback is attempted.

I tried stepping through the javascript to see if there were any errors in the POST but the post looks good to me. The last javascript to run before the error is executeRequest. While the pageRequestManager error blames the error on the server I am almost positive the error is generated client side. Instead of getting a meaningful response from the 'server' the response is totally blank.

these are the last scripts that are run before the error (What shows up in chrome's console on the failed post)

```
Sys$Net$XMLHttpExecutor$executeRequest   ScriptResource.axd:4102
Sys$Net$_WebRequestManager$executeRequest   ScriptResource.axd:4372
Sys$Net$WebRequest$invoke   ScriptResource.axd:4581
Sys$WebForms$PageRequestManager$_onFormSubmit  ScriptResource.axd:852
(anonymous function)  ScriptResource.axd:50
Sys$UI$DomEvent$addHandler.browserHandler
```

The final confounding aspect of this error is that it only occurs on the server and I cannot reproduce this locally. Because of this fact I at first thought this might be some sort of web.config setting, but even with my local web.config set identical to the server i don't get the issue locally. Also, why would server issue only affect some browsers? And only the more recent versions of webkit like 534+.

There were posts a couple years ago about a bug in the browser detection for safari/webkit but that javascript fix had no effect for me. I have also seen post where users recommended using an endrequesthandler to silence the code 0 error because its not a 'real' error, however, in my case there is something going on where the page isn't getting information so silencing that error doesn't fix anything.

so far the only fix, which isn't really a fix, is to turn off partial page updates.

Comment: so i just was able to generate another test page that had NO update panel and still generates an error only in chrome and ios safari. I get a error 101 connection reset error. So i think this connection error is the root error that caused the page request manager error.

Comment: based on packet monitoring software, the server is actually sending reset packets to the webkit browsers